# How can I test web conferencing issues?

Tags: sound, webcam, screencast, video-streaming, zoom-meeting

I'm experiencing problems with web conferencing softwares in my Ubuntu 21.04 installation (Plasma DE).
Everything is working, such as video streaming services (Youtube, Vimeo, and so on) except the web conferencing platforms:

- GoToMeeting
- Cisco Webex
- Zoom
- Google Meet
- Microsoft Teams
- BigBlueButton

It doesn't matter whether I use a browser (Chrome, Firefox) or desktop apps, it's pretty impossible to use the service: incredibly slow, lagging, audio issues both on my side and other participants sides, poor video performance when sharing webcam or desktop.

How can I investigate the problem? Every suggestion helping to point out what the issue could be depending of is much appreciated.

**EDIT: asked info**

*# lshw:*

```
mauroelitebook840
    description: Notebook
    product: HP EliteBook 840 G2 (N0Y00UC#ABU)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: A3009D510203
    serial: 5CG54129Z4
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5336AN G=N L=BUS B=HP S=ELI sku=N0Y00UC#ABU uuid=7F53D220-4B6C-E511-B454-820A7201C0FF
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 2216
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard
       physical id: 0
       version: KBC Version 96.56
       serial: PEVMP00WB9K4KW
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Hewlett-Packard
          physical id: d
          version: M71 Ver. 01.09
          date: 09/01/2015
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 10MiB
          capabilities: pci pcmcia upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 7
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 797MHz
          capacity: 2900MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap intel_pt xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: a
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 6
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 0
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             product: KHX2133C11S3L/8G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: 05321324
             slot: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             product: KHX2133C11S3L/8G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 03320924
             slot: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=bdw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 5500
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:47 memory:c0000000-c0ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:50 memory:c1330000-c1333fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:c1320000-c132ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.11.0-22-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.11
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=11 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: USB hub
                   product: USB2134B
                   vendor: SMSC
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@2:3
                   version: 60.82
                   capabilities: usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@2:4
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
                   vendor: Validity Sensors, Inc.
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@2:5
                   version: 1.04
                   serial: 0030fcc9c798
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Video
                   product: HP HD Webcam
                   vendor: SunplusIT INC.
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@2:7
                   version: 1.01
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.11.0-22-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.11
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: USB5534B
                   vendor: SMSC
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@3:3
                   version: 60.82
                   capabilities: usb-3.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:48 memory:c133b000-c133b01f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: enp0s25
             version: 03
             serial: b0:5a:da:b8:0f:c4
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:46 memory:c1300000-c131ffff memory:c133d000-c133dfff ioport:5080(size=32)
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: irq:51 memory:c1334000-c1337fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 memory:c1200000-c12fffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:3000(size=8192) memory:c1100000-c11fffff ioport:ae900000(size=2097152)
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:43 memory:c1100000-c1100fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 memory:c1000000-c10fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7265
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlo1
                version: 48
                serial: 4c:34:88:e6:c5:d0
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 7265-17.ucode ip=192.168.8.116 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:49 memory:c1000000-c1001fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:c1339000-c13393ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.11.0-22-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.11
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.03
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:44 ioport:50a8(size=8) ioport:50bc(size=4) ioport:50a0(size=8) ioport:50b8(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:c1338000-c13387ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:c133a000-c133a0ff ioport:ef80(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device HPQ8002
          vendor: Hewlett-Packard Co.
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device SYN3015
          vendor: Synaptics Inc
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device IFX0102
          vendor: Infineon Technologies AG
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=tpm_tis
     *-scsi
          physical id: 9
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: Samsung SSD 840
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: BB6Q
             serial: S1DHNSAF747644D
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=000a758c
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 835176a6-1117-4bde-80a6-92131d3cca0d
                size: 449GiB
                capacity: 449GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2014-09-13 21:02:58 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2021-06-24 19:59:40 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2021-06-24 07:46:17 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 15GiB
                capacity: 15GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux swap volume
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   version: 1
                   serial: 5329bae6-dfcc-438b-b403-80344adb8607
                   size: 15GiB
                   capacity: 15GiB
                   capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                   configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
  *-battery
       product: CM03050XL
       vendor: 333-54-22
       physical id: 1
       slot: Primary
       capacity: 50730mWh
       configuration: voltage=11,4V
```

*uname -a:*

```
Linux mauroEliteBook840 5.11.0-22-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 00:34:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

*lsb_release -a:*

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

Comment: What is your CPU model? How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try with softphones like [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/) or [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) (maybe Skype, or even TeamViewer also?).
Check only VoIP.

Also try the webcam, e.g. with `guvcview`.

And post some info like:

```
$ uname -a
$ lsb_release -a
```

and computer model.

**Related**:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting (old)

Comment: added asked info. No problem with gucview or teamiewer. Webcam works (with cheese or even with https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/ (17FPS)