# Zoom on Firefox has no incoming audio

Tags: sound, firefox, zoom-meeting

The issue is about Zoom web client on Firefox, and (in case that matters), the OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

Facts:

- Microphone works, other people can hear me (i.e. "outgoing" sound is ok)
- However, I cannot hear anything of what they say (i.e. "incoming" sound is completely missing)
- Permissions for microphone and camera are granted to Zoom as requested
- Most strange is this: **in the Settings, "Test Sound" works fine, I can hear the melody**
- Audio on other random websites (e.g. Youtube) works too
- Tried on two different computers (both Ubuntu 22.04/Firefox), same problem. (However, audio was fine on Chrome browser on one of the computers.)

I think the question can be boiled down to this:

**What is the difference between how "Test Sound" and the audio in the call itself works?**

At this point I believe they are two different mechanisms? How can I check/debug the mechanism used for the call?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1348459/1163497, https://askubuntu.com/q/1324160/1163497

Comment: I have the same problem with Firefox, Zoom, Fedora 37